# $\{x \in \mathbb R \,|\,a < x < b \} = \,]a; b[$, how can $\{x \in \mathbb N\,|\,a < x < b \}$ be written?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

As a student, we were learning about intervals. Wanting to go farther than the lecture, I tried to research how to use the "brackets form" for intervals in other ordered sets.

Mathematically, if, for $a \in \mathbb R$, $b \in \mathbb R$ and $a \le b$:
$$\{x \in \mathbb R\,|\,a < x < b \} = \,]a; b[$$

Is there, for $a \in \mathbb N$ and $b \in \mathbb N$ satisfying $a \le b$, is there an equivalent and more compact way of writing :
$$\{n \in \mathbb N\,|\, a < n < b\}$$

$\mathbb N$ is only an exemple, I am looking for a generalization over all ordered sets

Comment: An intersection would do... or even shorter: no needed specification due to the context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it as: 
$$]a;b[ ~\cap~ \Bbb N$$

Answer (score 0):

Some authors use $$\overline{a+1, b-1}:=\{n\in\Bbb N\mid a<n<b\}.$$

Comment: While I understand that notation shouldn't be discussed reached a certain point, why is there the $+1$ and $-1$ ?

Comment: Because $a<n<b$, @Sachiko.Shinozaki.